# Handling "net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID" error in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic4

While making an "http" request in ionic4, the response neither comes under success callback nor get handled by the error handling block. Instead it keeps on loading. Please provide me a way to handle this error in ionic4(Clientside).

I have tried with setting timeout for the request. But I am using a common http request for all the API calls in my application, so I am unable to set a common unique time interval for all the API call in my http request.

Comment: "the response neither comes under success callback nor get handled by the error handling block" ...can you post the code for the error handling block?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the remote server is setup incorrectly, or your local time is wrong on the computer.

Are you just trying to gracefully show an error in this scenario?

You should be using https anyway as its a requirement out of the box with a recent version of Android.

Comment: Thank you rtpHarry for answering.  Yes, it would be better show an error in it this case.